# What is the best value for "Unit Separator" in XML?

Tags: html, xml, database, entity

I used Unit Separator (US/0x1f) in database. When I export to XML 1.0 file, it is not accepted and leave the attribute with empty value.

I have data in database like this:

"option1=10;option2=20;option3=aaa[US]bbb[US]ccc;"

I'm assuming to export to XML 1.0 file like this:

<elementname, attr1="option1=10;option2=20;option3=aaa[US]bbb[US]ccc;"/>

However, the [US] is not accepted by XML 1.0. Any suggestions?

I can replace '\37' (oct 37, hex 1f) with something like "XXX", "$", "(0x1f)"... before writing to XML;

I can replace it when importing from XML and write to database. However, if I replace it with "& # x 1 F ;", which is the HTML Entity for Unit separator, I end up with "& a m p ; # x 1 F ;", which is definitely not what I wanted.

If I manually modify the XML file to "& # x 1 F ;", I can not use MSXML to load it, giving error "Invalid Unicode Character".

Any suggestions?

Thank you

---

**Summary:**

Let's make an analogy: Let's think about how the compiler works, there are two phases: "Pre-compile" and "Compile".

For XML File Generation, it acts like the "Compile" phase. E.g. convert "<" to "& l t ;"

However, the Unit Separator is not supported by XML 1.0, so the "Compile" phase will not convert it to HTML Entity "& # x 1 F ;"

So we have to seek solution in the "Pre-Compile" phase, which is our own application's responsibility.

When writing:

```
Option1: <unit>aaa</unit><unit>bbb</unit>
Option2: simply use "_x241F_" to replace "\37" in the string if "_x241F_" is not conflicting with any existing token in the string.
```

When reading:

```
According to Option1: Load the elements, catenate to a single string with "\37" as separator.
According to Option2: simply use "\37" to replace "_x241F_".
```

I've also found out that MSXML (even the highest version MSXML6.dll) will not load XML 1.1 .

So if we are unfortunately using MSXML, we have to write our own "Pre-Compile" code to handle the Unicode characters before feeding the "Compile" phase.

Note: I borrowed the idea of "_ x 2 4 1 F _" from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx).

Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no HTML *entity* for U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR. Besides, HTML entities would be irrelevant when dealing with generic XML.

The *character references* would be `&#x1f;` and `&#31;`, in HTML and in XML, but the character is not allowed in HTML or in XML. For XML 1.0, which this seems to be about, please refer to section [2.2 Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets), where the normative definition is the following production (the associated comment is misleading, and comments are non-normative):

```
Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] |
                            [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

The conclusions to be drawn depend on the meaning and purpose of UNIT SEPARATOR in the text. It has no generally defined meaning; it is up to applications to assign a meaning to it and process it accordingly.

Usually UNIT SEPARATOR is used to separate units of some kind, so the natural approach would be to process the incoming data so that instead of such separators, the data, when converted to XML format, has units denoted by markup. So for data like aaa[US]bbb[US]ccc where [US] is UNIT SEPARATOR, you would generate something like `<unit>aaa</unit><unit>bbb</unit><unit>ccc</unit>`.

Comment: Thanks Jukka. I have data in database like this: "option1=10;option2=20;option3=aaa[US]bbb[US]ccc;"    I'm assuming to export to XML 1.0 file like this: <elementname, attr1="option1=10;option2=20;option3=aaa[US]bbb[US]ccc;"/>, However, the [US] is not accepted by XML 1.0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Jukka, could you explain "but the character is not allowed in HTML or in XML" in a bit more detail? I did experience that if I manually modify XML file by inputting "& # x 1 F;", the MSXML can not load the XML file, giving error "Invalid Unicode Character". Is this what you mean?

Comment: Since U+001F is not allowed by the production for Char, its presence is a well-formedness violation, hence a fatal error by XML 1.0 rules: a conforming XML processor must report the error and must not resume normal processing. So MSXML does what it is required to do.

Comment: Without knowing more about the data and its intended use, it is difficult to recommend any particular conversion. But the fragment shown would perhaps best be mapped to XML like `<options><option1>10</option1><option2>20</option2><option3><unit>aaa</unit><unit>bbb</unit><unit>ccc</unit></option3></options>`. Or for a simpler document structure, though more verbose markup, `<options><option1><unit>10</unit></option1><option2><unit>20</unit></option2><option3><unit>aaa</unit><unit>bbb</unit><unit>ccc</unit></option3></options>`

Comment: Hi Jukka, I will definitely adopt your suggestion in future project. However, for the current legacy project, I have to replace unit separator to some literal. Besides that, I have two more question. 1. What's the reason you guess MSXML can not parse XML 1.1 (it is doing correctly conforming XML 1.0, but 1.1?)? 2. I want to use "_ x 2 4 1 F _" to replace unit separator. I "borrowed" this idea from Sql Server's For XML escape rule, which is for element name[but I used in attribute value or element value during my "pre-compile" process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx)

Comment: MSXML is limited to XML 1.0 probably because XML 1.0 is what XML generally means; XML 1.1 has not gained much use or support. Regarding the replacement of U+001F by another character, I guess you need to find out a character that is valid in XML 1.0 and cannot appear in actual data. Perhaps U+00B6 PILCROW SIGN “¶” would be safe enough in practice, and it would be easily distinguishable when reading XML source code.

Answer (score 2):

This website

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm

suggests one of the following:

HTML Entity (decimal)   `&#31;`

HTML Entity (hex)   `&#x1f;`

Comment: Great! That's what I'm after.

Comment: I have tried that with various XML processors, but all seem to reject `&#x1f;` as an invalid character.